# CUDA, code works on one GPU machine, doesn't work on another

Tags: c, cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I am puzzled by the behaviour of the following snippet:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

// kernel
__global__ void CheckAddressing(float * d_Result, int numCols, int numRows)
{
    printf("%d\n", threadIdx.x);
    if(threadIdx.x<16)
    {
        d_Result[threadIdx.x]=float(364.66);

    }
}


////////

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int TotalSize = 16;
    float * d_Result;

    float * h_Result;

        cudaSetDevice(0);

    h_Result = (float *)malloc(TotalSize*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void **) &d_Result, TotalSize*sizeof(float));
    CheckAddressing<<<dim3(1),dim3(16)>>>(d_Result, 8,8);


    cudaMemcpy(h_Result, d_Result, TotalSize*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for(int n=0; n<16; n++)
    {
        printf("%f\t", h_Result[n]);
    }
        printf("\n");


// free GPU memory
        cudaFree(d_Result);
        free(h_Result);
    return 0;

}
```

It works on one machine (I compile with `nvcc -arch=sm_30`) and returns 364.66 (16 times). However on another machine running Cuda 5.5 it returns all zeros. Any idea what can be happening?

UPDATE:

```
cuda-memcheck ./test
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors

nvidia-smi
Fri Apr 18 14:45:05 2014       
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 331.44     Driver Version: 331.44         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K20Xm         Off  | 0000:02:00.0     Off |                    0 |
| N/A   20C    P0    50W / 235W |     11MiB /  5759MiB |     99%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Process name                                     Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running compute processes found                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: The easy way to find out would be to add some error checking. Every API call (and the kernel launch) returns or reports a status. Checking those will explain what is happening.

Comment: I am doing `cudamemcheck` when I run the code. Does it suffice to check for errors? If not, what is the proper way of getting the reports of errors?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14038589/681865

Comment: you run the code on the machine that is returning all zeroes, and `cuda-memcheck` is reporting zero errors?  Can you show your actual invocation and actual output from that machine? (paste it into your question).  What is the machine configuration and OS?

Comment: Robert, the machine is Dirac @ Nersc. I land on one of the nodes interactively (http://www.nersc.gov/users/computational-systems/testbeds/dirac/), compile the code, and just run it in the same interactive mode. I am also in contact with nersc support, but I thought I might have mistake in the code, doesn't look like that.  if I don't do the `malloc` on the host array and just do `float h_Result[16]`, the same code gives random numbers

Comment: Robert, yes, `cuda-memcheck` reports 0 errors and output is all zeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dirac mentions Fermi GPUs on [its banner](http://www.nersc.gov/users/computational-systems/testbeds/dirac/).  If you are on a node with Fermi GPUs, your compile command is incorrect:

```
-arch=sm_30
```

is used for Kepler GPUs.

Try:

```
-arch=sm_20
```

instead.

I was confused by the fact that `cuda-memcheck` was reporting no errors, but the type of error you are encountering is a type that `cuda-memcheck` will not necessarily catch.  Specifically, there are a category of launch failure errors that can only be trapped by the [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14038589/681865) that @talonmies suggested.  Specifically note the error checking code that is required immediately after a kernel launch.

When you compile for `-arch=sm_30` and try to run it on a Fermi (`sm_20`) machine, the kernel launch will immediately fail, but all other subsequent CUDA API calls will report no failure.

The [detail page for Dirac](http://www.nersc.gov/users/computational-systems/testbeds/dirac/node-and-gpu-configuration/) does mention a couple Kepler nodes/GPUs:

> •1 node: Tesla K20Xm
>
> •1 node: Tesla K40c

I believe your code compiled with `-arch=sm_35` should run correctly on those nodes.

And I also note that there are even some older ("Tesla" family) GPUs/nodes:

> •4 nodes:  1 C1060 NVIDIA Tesla GPU with 4GB of memory and 240 parallel CUDA processor cores.
>
> • 1 node:  4 C1060 Nvidia Tesla GPU's, each with 4GB of memory and 240 parallel CUDA processor cores.

For those nodes, you would need to compile with:

```
-arch=sm_13
```

but don't forget to use the proper cuda error checking, any time you are having difficulty with a CUDA code.

Or you could use [nvcc extended notation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#extended-notation) to specify a compile and binary/executable for all 3 types.

Using extended notation, for the 3 different GPU architectures on that cluster (that I can see):

```
nvcc -gencode arch=compute_13,code=sm_13 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 ...
```

Comment: I tried it with both `-arch=sm_20` and without specifying arch. Still get all zeros. This is very confusing

Comment: It will be confusing since you have at least 3 different node types in that machine, and you may want a code that runs on any of the 3 types.  For that I suggest using the extended notation.

Comment: for the kepler node you are on (according to your `nvidia-smi` output) you could just try `-arch=sm_35` also.

Comment: The extended notation that you mentioned in your answer (last line) finally gave me the result I need. Thank you, Robert, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: FWIW since you have `printf` in the kernel, your code can't be compiled as-is for an `sm_13` machine and so you should probably delete that `-gencode` entry.  You probably already figured that out.

Comment: To be honest, I am still not sure why the code started working when I submit it via the queue using the extended notation. I have still not managed to get successful results on the node itself interactively (I tried all -arch choices)

Comment: Yes, I do think something else is going on.  Adding the cuda error checking might be instructive.  There may be a machine configuration difference (modules, etc) between the interactive and non-interactive jobs.  A K20 GPU should be able to run code that has been compiled with `-arch=sm_20`, or `-arch=sm_30`, or `-arch=sm_35`.  I tried it myself just now with your code to confirm.